# GWT: Setting emptyListMessage for CellList

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to set the empty list message for a `CellList`:

```
    <c:CellList ui:field="membersList">
        <emptyListMessage>
            <g:Label text="No members found" />
        </emptyListMessage>
    </c:CellList>
```

This fails with the error:

```
    [ERROR] Found unexpected child element Element <emptyListMessage>
```

I also tried:

```
<c:CellList ui:field="membersList" emptyListMessage="No members found" />
```

which fails with the error:

```
    [ERROR] Cannot parse value: "No members found" as type SafeHtml
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As CellList.setEmptyListMessage expects a SafeHtml string you cant use it this way in the uibinder xml.  Just set it in your ViewImpl class.